# Eliminating Some Combinations From a List of Lists in Python

Tags: python, list, conditional-statements, combinations, combinatorics

The code below gives all possible combinations of 6 numbers from 1 to 52. It gives these combinations in a list of lists. However I want to eliminate some of these combinations.

The combinations I want to eliminate are the ones where each element in the combination belongs to a different number group. The different number groups are given in the code and denoted by D, T, L, H, K, M.

In the code I attempt to do this elimination using an if statement, but I realize that doing it this way I would have to type 720 combinations and that's impractical and tedious.

How do I do this in a simple and quick way?

```
import numpy as np
import math
from itertools import permutations
import itertools
import collections



perm = itertools.combinations(range(1, 53), 6)
res = [list(val) for val in perm]
size = len(res)

D = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
T = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
L = [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
H = [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39]
K = [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]
M = [50, 51, 52]


output_list = []

for i in range(0, 20358520):
        if (
                res[i][0] not in D
                and res[i][1] not in T
                and res[i][2] not in L
                and res[i][3] not in H
                and res[i][4] not in K
                and res[i][5] in M
            )
            or 
            (
                res[i][0] not in D
                and res[i][2] not in T
                and res[i][1] not in L
                and res[i][3] not in H
                and res[i][4] not in K
                and res[i][5] not in M
            )
            or ... to 720 combinations:
                            

           output_list.append([res[i][0],
                               res[i][1],
                               res[i][2],
                               res[i][3],
                               res[i][4],
                               res[i][5]]
                            )

print(output_list )
print(len(output_list))
```

Comment: last line of the 1st conditional: `and res[i][5] in M` is really correct or you forgot a `not in`?

Comment: you could use `all` with a generator comprehension to reduce all the `and`s.... but it's not so clear what (or _how_) are  you trying do

Comment: Perhaps you can [edit] your question and put there small example and required output.

Comment: @smallpepperz how do I go about that sir? yes that should be not in, thanks.

Comment: @Kelly Bundy, you're right importing permutations was unnecessary. Thanks.

Comment: @Andrej Kesely, I'll try Ahmed AEK's answer first. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to check the intersection between each array and the current combination is not 1 for all of them.

```
import numpy as np
import math
import itertools
import collections



perm = itertools.combinations(range(1, 53), 6)
res = [list(val) for val in perm]
size = len(res)

D = set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
T = set([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19])
L = set([20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29])
H = set([30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39])
K = set([40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49])
M = set([50, 51, 52])

output_list = []

for comb in res:
        if not all(len(other.intersection(comb)) == 1 for other in (D,T,L,H,K,M)):

           output_list.append(comb)

print(output_list )
print(len(output_list))
```

**Edit:** For faster excution the condition could change to `if any(len(other.intersection(comb)) != 1 for other in (D,T,L,H,K,M)):`

Answer (score 1):

Edit: @Ahmed AEK's answer using sets will run much faster than this, but it uses the same fundamental logic.

Since the number groups are mutually exclusive and the number of numbers in the combination is the same as the number of groups, you can just check if each one is satisfied or not. The logic can then be compressed into a one-line list comprehension.

```
output_list = [combo for combo in res if all([any([n in combo for n in group]) for group in [D, T, L, H, K, M]])]
```

The long version with clearer logic:

```
output_list = []
for combo in res:
    groups = [D, T, L, H, K, M]
    satisfied = []
    for group in groups:
        for num in group:
            if num in combo:
               satisfied.append(True)
               break
        else:
            satisfied.append(False)
    if all(satisfied):
        output_list.append(combo)
```